# Legacy cross-compilation functionality unexpectedly vanished—how can I figure out what happened?

Tags: linux, gcc, cmake, cygwin, cross-platform

I am developing in a very restricted environment. For bureaucratic reasons, I need to do the following:

(1) Compile an executable on Windows for a Linux target;

(2) Do so without installing new software or packages;

(3) Do so via Cygwin command terminal.

These are fixed constants that I absolutely cannot change.

Previously, for reasons I can't explain, Cygwin defaulted to compiling for a Linux target, and I was able to maintain this process without issues. Researching the issue, I am unsure how it wound up defaulting to this behavior.

However, earlier today, I introduced a coworker's script to streamline my build process, putting the CMakeFiles and CMakeCache.txt in a build directory rather than in my project folder. As a part of this, my original CMakeFiles and CMakeCache directory were lost.

I then attempted to manually export a CC and CXX path to a compiler for compilation, trying every *gcc.exe and *g++.exe executable I could find on my computer. I am aware that most, if not all, cross-platform compilation tools label cross-compilation executables with Linux in their name, but no such files were found in any Cygwin drive locations.

I have additionally logging out and having another user log in to try and build, but this had the same results.

I tried restoring what CMakeFiles and CMakeCache files were still in the recycle bin, but reusing those proved ineffective.

What I know:

1. There is a /opt/gcc-tools/ directory in Cygwin that does not contain a gcc executable, but during the initial installation of the project into the system, someone was messing around with it. There are no other installed files or programs in the /opt/ directory.
2. Setting the CC and CXX paths back to null cause CMake to default to /usr/bin/cc and /usr/bin/c++. There are no linux versions of these files.
3. MinGW is installed, and I am unsure if it's related to cross-platform weirdness.
4. There are various LINUX-{GNU/INTEL/CLANG}.cmake files in the usr/share/cmake/modules/platform section of Cygwin. These are probably just used for checking cross-compilation, but if they can be edited to get things working I would have no objections.

My build.sh file looks as such:

```
export CC=/usr/bin/gcc.exe
export CXX=/usr/bin/gcc.exe

pushd build > /dev/null

cmake ..
make all install -j8


popd /dev/null
```

and previously was a simple

```
cmake .
make
```

without install or -j8

I realize that this is a difficult issue to debug without access to a terminal and the system. My one goal is to get cmake to once again spit out a.out files rather than a.exe files. Hopefully, this will shed some light on how the system ever worked in the first place in the process.

Comment: Your best chance of success is to rollback the state of your machine to yesterday or earlier on the chance that something you did very recently caused your problem. Otherwise see if you can determine when your machine last did what you describe here and try to get files from then restored. Consult your system administrators to see if they can do this for you. In the mean time, try not to make things worse. ...

Comment: ... And consider these possibilities. Did you have a virtual machine where you booted into a linux install? Are you missing some shares or removable HDs? Did you use the windows subsystem for linux? Did this machine use to dual boot into linux? Or did you boot from a live disk or USB drive? Has you machine been upgrade from say Win7 to Win10? Good luck.